# Substitute different equation parameters (e.g. slope) when batch processing raster calculator in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, batch

I have 15 multiband rasters for a total of 45 total single-bands (5 dates x 3 sensors x 3 bands per sensor) for which I need to apply a unique calibration function in the form Y=A*[exp(B*X)] to for each band and date. I have a spreadsheet with all the A and B parameter values corresponding to dates and band IDs.

Is there a feasible way for me to apply these functions iteratively in model builder (I'm be willing to learn how to do so in Python as well) to my data? Essentially, how would I tell the raster calculator to substitute the parameters for each date?

My thoughters were to rename all the rasters in the format "Sensor_date.tiff", then try to split them into individual bands using the "Make Raster Layer" tool . I would then feed those temporary outputs into the raster calculator and output the fully-calibrated single-band rasters. Ideally, I also want to feed those outputs into the raster calculator multiple times to determine separate indices.